# Multiple Images base64 String are not sending on server without compress

Tags: android, soap, android-camera, android-ksoap2

I want to capture five images in my app and sent their base64 string to server without compress. I have searched on google and read lots of articles after that I found the solution to send base64 string without compress. Now what I want that when I am sending only one image then its saving sucessfully to my server but when I am sending two or more than two images then i got below error I am not getting what is the issue. I think something I am doing wrong.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {

            //user is returning from capturing an image using the camera
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) {
                byte[] inputData=null;
                //Uri uri = data.getData();
                //get the Uri for the captured image
                Uri uri = picUri;
                Log.d("picUri", uri.toString());

                InputStream iStream = null;
                try {
                    iStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    inputData = getBytes(iStream);
                    encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(inputData, Base64.DEFAULT);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //carry out the crop operation
                performCrop();

            } else if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
                //get the returned data
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                //get the cropped bitmap
                thePic = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

                if (setInImageView.equals("1")) {

                    imageView1.setImageBitmap(thePic);

                    image1 =encodedString;

                } else if (setInImageView.equals("2")) {

                    imageView2.setImageBitmap(thePic);

                    image2 = encodedString;

                } else if (setInImageView.equals("3")) {

                    imageView3.setImageBitmap(thePic);

                    image3 = encodedString;

                } else if (setInImageView.equals("4")) {

                    imageView4.setImageBitmap(thePic);

                    image4 = encodedString;

                } else if (setInImageView.equals("5")) {

                    imageView5.setImageBitmap(thePic);

                    image5 = encodedString;

                    String str;
                    str = "1";

                }

            }
        }
    }



public void selectImage1() {
        try {
            //use standard intent to capture an image
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            String imageFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/picture.jpg";
            File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);
            picUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile); // convert path to Uri
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            //display an error message
            String errorMessage = "oops! your device doesn't support capturing images!";
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    //OnClick for set Image in Image View
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.camera1:
                // code
                setInImageView="1";
                selectImage1();
                break;
            case R.id.camera2:
                // code
                setInImageView="2";
                selectImage1();
                break;
            case R.id.camera3:
                // code
                setInImageView="3";
                selectImage1();
                break;
            case R.id.camera4:
                // code
                setInImageView="4";
                selectImage1();
                break;
            case R.id.camera5:
                // code
                setInImageView="5";
                selectImage1();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }


    public static byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 10240;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }

}
```

Below is my error -

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file. ---> Maximum request length exceeded.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@97e9569
```

Comment: `sent their base64 string to server without compress`. What kind of compression? I dont understand. You first expanded the amount of bytes by 30% by encoding to base64. And now ... Why do you talk about compression?

Comment: Thanks greenapps I got your point. I talk about because I saw lots of example but I am getting only 40kb size of image which is not useful for me but from this this code i got 1.4mb size of image. Why its not saving all the five image to server ? Am doing something wrong ?

Comment: My issue is I want to save all the five images but its giving error which I mention in above question. But if i send only one Image then its save on server.

Comment: The error is simple, you exceeded the maximum request length.

Comment: How can I solve that ? will you please provide an example ?

Comment: Resize your image.

Comment: I am not getting how to resize again ?

Comment: What i do not understand is than when you have a lot of image bytes that you are going to make 30 % more before upload. Better: just upload the image bytes. Well depends on the server of course.

Comment: Hey greenapps. Its showing me croped image in my ImageView but on server its sending full image. I want to send cropped image.

Comment: Well please do as you want. You don't have to tell me ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it and hope it helps others. I have add below line in my web service. Now its saving all five Image sucessfully and very good quality and 1.40 MB size.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: 1048576 is 1.0 MB.